# Avoid duplication of form input element ID in Django

Tags: html, django, forms

When two forms on one page have the same-named field, Django will generate invalid HTML:

```
<!--one form -->
<input id="id_name"..../>
...
<!--another form-->
<input id="id_name".../>
```

Invalid because two or more nodes share the same id.

How can this be avoided?

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use form prefixes, as documented [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#prefixes-for-forms).