# two forms with same input id in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have multiple forms on a page which pass an id to the controller via hidden inputs. As I am using strongly typed views for these I think I need to keep the Id for each of these to be the same. It works currently though I think it's bad practice. How should I handle this? In Django there are form prefix values is there an equivalent?

[Avoid duplication of form input element ID in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252826/avoid-duplication-of-form-input-element-id-in-django)

Here are the two forms I am using:

```
        <form action="/Course/CropImage" method="post"> 
            <input id="CourseId" name="CourseId" type="hidden" value="<%= Model.CourseId %>" />
            <input id="X" name="X" type="hidden" value="<%= Model.X %>" />
            <input id="Y" name="Y" type="hidden" value="<%= Model.Y %>" />
            <input id="W" name="W" type="hidden" value="<%= Model.W %>" />
            <input id="H" name="H" type="hidden" value="<%= Model.H %>" />
            <input type="submit" value="Crop" />
        </form>

        <form action="/Course/UploadImage" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            <input id="CourseId" name="CourseId" type="hidden" value="<%= Model.CourseId %>" />
            <label for="Image">Select Image:</label><input id="Image" type="file" name="Select Image"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
        </form>
```

Comment: Could you show the code of your view page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are having 2 view models (one for the crop, one for the upload) you can prefix them like this (you can use html helpers):

```
    <form action="/Course/CropImage" method="post"> 
        <input id="Crop_CourseId" name="Crop.CourseId" type="hidden" value="<%= Model.CourseId %>" />
        <input id="Crop_X" name="Crop.X" type="hidden" value="<%= Model.X %>" />
        <input id="Crop_Y" name="Crop.Y" type="hidden" value="<%= Model.Y %>" />
        <input id="Crop_W" name="Crop.W" type="hidden" value="<%= Model.W %>" />
        <input id="Crop_H" name="Crop.H" type="hidden" value="<%= Model.H %>" />
        <input type="submit" value="Crop" />
    </form>

    <form action="/Course/UploadImage" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <input id="Upload_CourseId" name="Upload.CourseId" type="hidden" value="<%= Model.CourseId %>" />
        <label for="Image">Select Image:</label><input id="Upload_Image" type="file" name="Upload.Image"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </form>
```

and then bind attribute with the prefix to you controller actions like this:

```
public ActionResult CropImage([Bind(Prefix="Crop")]CropViewModel viewModel)
{
  // do something
}


public ActionResult UploadImage([Bind(Prefix="Upload")]UploadViewModel viewModel)
{
  // do something
}
```

Comment: For anyone trying to do the same with the new strongly-typed template system, you just put a prefix in the appropriate overload of a *For function for `htmlFieldName`: `Html.EditorFor(m => m.SomeComplexCropProperty, null, "Crop")`. The `null` in `templateName` sets it up to use the default but it can be overridden as well.

Comment: @patridge Good tip. And if you use editor templates for the whole model you can also specify the prefix like this: `Html.EditorForModel(null, "thePrefix")`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bad practise. They are completely different forms so that makes the input element unique. You will not make your server code or client js/markup any more semantic by adding prefixes.

Comment: The OP had the ID's the same on two different HTML elements this is bad pratice. Same name is fine. Same ID is a violation of HTML and one that actually matters, what will getElemenetById return?

Comment: @David: I didn't see that. But you're right, same IDs is bad yes.

Answer (score 0):

I always prefix my column-names with the table name. Here's the database-layout of my latest MVC-project (using strongly typed views and LINQ to SQL):

```
WeblogEntries:
- WeblogEntryId
- WeblogEntryHeaderText
- WeblogEntryBodyText
- WeblogEntryDate

WeblogComments:
- WeblogCommentId
- WeblogCommentBodyText
- WeblogCommentDate

WeblogErrors
- WeblogErrorId
- WeblogErrorExceptionMessage
- WeblogErrorExceptionStackTrace
- WeblogErrorDate
```

These naming conventions work great with the entity classes that gets generated using dbml-files.

Comment: Why would you add unnecessary characters like that? Maybe in MSAccess tables, but .NET is strongly typed. Surely there is no gain for adding extra complication like this?

Comment: I do this to avoid encountering the problem you are describing in your question :) But perhaps I'm misunderstanding your question?