# MVC3 - jQuery datepicker when multiple elements have the same ID

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, datepicker, updatemodel

I have a weird situation (don't we all?) with datepickers and want to get some advice.

I have a screen with a list of Locations, and for each Location, they can click Edit and edit that location.  The Edit  displays below the Edit link, and they can edit multiple locations at one time.  This means the same View is rendered on the screen multiple times, and therefore multiple fields will exist with the same id (editing 4 locations will result in 4 "DateOpened" fields).

So, when I load my View, javascript adds datepickers to any fields that need it like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var elements = $(".NeedsDatePicker > td > input");
    $(".NeedsDatePicker > td > input").datepicker();
    $(".NeedsDatePicker").removeClass("NeedsDatePicker");
});
```

Works fine, but, as you've probably already figured out, when I click a date on the calender, it populates the first "DateOpened" field when multiple Edit windows are open.

Is there a way to tell the datepicker to use the field WITHIN a certain parent, like you can for general jQuery selects?

```
$("#DateOpened", "Location-134").doWhatever...
```

...or is there a way to give the fields different id's without breaking MVC's UpdateModel() function?  Or any other advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely keep IDs unique within an HTML DOM. Most, if not all, DOM manipulation libraries/frameworks, including jQuery, have this assumption built-in.

There are a few questions on SO WRT to avoid the same IDs in the form:

- [two forms with same input id in asp.net mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778307/two-forms-with-same-input-id-in-asp-net-mvc)
- [how to prevent html input id duplication on asp.net mvc 3 when a model contains multiple elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080935/how-to-prevent-html-input-id-duplication-on-asp-net-mvc-3-when-a-model-contains)

Comment: But won't that break MVC's TryUpdateModel?  Instead of finding a field named "LocationAddress", it would find LocationAddress1, 2, etc, which would not match the model it's binding to.

Comment: If you were to have multiple elements with the same ID, wouldn't that update the same element multiple times? I think a way around this may be to have a view model wrapping the models with the same property names.